# open cart attaching the controller to the template

Tags: templates, opencart

I have created header_top.tpl in the catalouge folder (down in the theme "common" folder) and then a controller in the controller folder. But I do not know how should I render a template with a controller (and send data from controller to the template to be further parsed by the template).

I know `$this->render()` does render the template but what happens before to it is vague to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a condition similar to the below the code in your controller file. Replace with your template file in that section as given below:

```
 if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header_top.tpl')) {
      $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header_top.tpl';
 } else {
      $this->template = 'default/template/common/header_top.tpl';
 }
```

Values set as `$this->data['sitename'] = 'stackoverflow';` in controller file can be used in template file like `echo $sitename`;

Have a nice day !!

Comment: then how the data is passed to the template? For instance I want to get the name of the user and passe it to the template. such as: `$name = get_current_user_name(); $data["name"]=$name;`